# Are there any C compilers which let you block the usage of specific libraries and functions?

Tags: c, compilation, c-preprocessor

Does anyone know if there are any C compilers which let you block the usage of specific libraries and functions?

For instance, let's say I wanted to block access to float.h and tried to compile a program that had "#include ". I'd want the compile to fail and some sort of message indicating it was because float.h cannot be included.

Or, if I wanted to block access to sqrt() and pow() in math.h, but include all the other functions in that library, so a program that had the line "double hold = pow(2.0, 3.0);" wouldn't compile and would worn that a blocked function was being called.

I've tried searching online for something like this but I don't think I know the correct terms to search for because I can't seem to find any results pertaining to what I'm actually looking for.

Comment: What are the usecases for such a feature? You can always re-`#define` the blocked functions/types.

Comment: If you're using GCC, [`#pragma GCC poison`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/cpp/Pragmas.html) can be useful to block specific functions. It won't help for whole headers though.

Comment: I'm trying to write a program which teaches people the C language. They type in code, it passes their code to a compiler and runs it, piping the output to a file which is then read by my program.I want to make sure they can't shoot themselves in the foot by blocking access to some of the more dangerous functions and also make sure they can't redirect the output elsewhere than I intend.

Comment: @Quentin `#pragma GCC poison` does exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks Quentin!

Comment: @PolkaPunk You might be better off using something pre-made like Ideone.com and finding an API for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With e.g., gcc, you can do the following to prevent certain includes:

1. Create a failing stub for each header include that you want to fail:

**float.h:**

```
#error "You must not include me"
```

2. Make sure those stubs will override your system libraries:

   ```
   $ export CPATH=$PWD
   ```

Compiling a c-file that tries to include `"float.h"` or `<float.h>` in this environment will then fail.

Of course, this is circumventable. All you need is declare the functions declared in the missing headers manually.

A better option might be to create a global include (`-include`) where you 
`#pragma GCC poison` all symbols that should not be used anywhere in your programs.

You can also inspect crated object files with `nm` for the unresolved symbols that you don't want resolved by the c librard and stop the build if such symbols are found.

Comment: `pragma GCC poison` does exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks PSkocik!